# How can I understand that whether the shared preferences file is exists or not

Tags: android

I wrote the following code.But when I press the button and relaunch the program, I see the `There is no the file.xml file` message again.

```
File file = new File("/data/data/" + getPackageName() +  "/shared_prefs/" + getPackageName()+ "file.xml");
        if (file.exists())
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is the file.xml file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There is no the file.xml file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
            sharedpreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("file", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("file","I am a file");

            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: The SharedPreferences file will be created automatically when you store a preference, is there any reason why you're accessing it directly?

Comment: Thank you. My purpose from above code is that when I have no the `file.xml` I see the `There is no the file.xml file` message and when I press on the button, I can create the `file.xml` and when I launch the code I see the `There is the file.xml file` message.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file.exists())
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is the file.xml file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"There is no the file.xml file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
you  can  test the  code in you project.
that  "There is no the file.xml file"  is a  message. you can  change it.

 if(file.exists()){
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is not the file.xml file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There is the file.xml file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```